# Groovy test class using @ContextHierarchy

Tags: groovy, spring-test, context-configuration

I am using Groovy for my Spring application and I try to use multiple XML beans configurations inside my test. I tried using `@ContextHierarchy` but following usage example didn't work:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextHierarchy({@ContextConfiguration("a.xml"), ContextConfiguration("b.xml")})
public class MyTest {

...

}
```

I have also tried:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"a.xml", "b.xml"})
```

but it didn't work as well.

As I understand Groovy doesn't like the "{" "}", because it has different mean to it....?

How can I write the Testclass in groovy with two conifiguration xmls defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiple XML configuration sources with `@ContextConfiguration` annotation. Let's say I have 2 XML config files located in `src/main/resources` - `beans1.xml` and `beans2.xml`. I can use them in my test with:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = ['classpath:beans1.xml', 'classpath:beans2.xml'])
```

The main difference comparing to Java is that Groovy uses `[]` for arrays instead of Java's `{}`, because `{}` represents Groovy's closure.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's it :-)